# Can Pathauto fallback to another pattern if the first pattern yields an empty path?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases

I want pages to have an auto generated path if they are in a menu and another one if they are not in the menu; not an empty path like Pathauto currently generates if the page is not in a menu.

How can I do that?

**Details:** I'm using this pattern for my pages content type which works perfectly when a page is in a menu.

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:menu-link]
```

The problem is, when a page is not in a menu, it gets an empty path. I want to give it another path based on the "title" of the page, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, conditional tokens was requested many times and never implemented, so fallback you ask for is not possible.

You can use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) instead. [Description on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/comment/1822544#comment-1822544) claims it's easy - instead of pathauto, set up a rule on node creation / update, and create aliases needed. Rules support conditions, as you can see in [Rules examples](https://drupal.org/project/rules_example) project, so you can create aliases conditionally all right.

Comment: Sad to hear that. If I find a better answer I'll update here for future reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can now achieve this using hook_pathauto_pattern_alter().  Something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_pattern_alter().
 */
function mymodule_pathauto_pattern_alter(&$pattern, array $context) {
  // Alter any node entity path patterns we need to
  if (isset($context['data']['node'])) {
    $node = $context['data']['node'];

    switch ($node->type) {
      case 'page':
        // Check condition, and change the pattern when appropriate
        $pattern = '[node:title]';
        break;

    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, this changes the pattern depending on node type no matter what. I needed a way to change the pattern and regenerate the path only when the original pattern fails to generate a proper path.

Answer (score 0):

I took what m4olivei wrote and made it work for falling back to node title if no menu item is generated:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_pathauto_pattern_alter().
 */
function mymodule_pathauto_pattern_alter(&$pattern, array $context) {
  // Set up pathauto fallback to node title if no menu item is generated
  if (isset($context['data']) && isset($context['data']['node'])) {
    if (isset($context['data']['node']->menu) && isset($context['data']['node']->menu['enabled'])) {
      if (!$context['data']['node']->menu['enabled']) {
        $pattern = '[node:title]';
      }
    }
  }
}
```